# Replacing text in a .nfo file

Tags: python, encoding, character-encoding, ascii

I have a colors.nfo file where I want to replace variables and get a new generated nfo-file without losing the template.

There are ascii-signs which I don't know how to handle.
Every time I load with file.open and replace the variables and write it to a new file, there are weird signs and the template is destroyed.

Here is an image of the file:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yd3Z.png

Here is the uploaded file to handle with:
[Click to download](https://www.file-upload.net/download-13759826/colors.nfo.html) -- Hope its okay. otherwise i will delete!

Hope you understand the problem.
Want to replace the "%REPLACE1%", "%REPLACE2%" and "%REPLACE3%" with for example "BLACKGREY", "REDWHITE"....

- Tried to load it in a string with f.open
- after I replaced it with string.replace("%REPLACE1", "BLACKGREY")
- after I write a new file with f.write
- file is destroyed and the ascii signs are unreadable and the template is not like before

Code Example:

```
replaceString = []
f = open("colors.nfo")
for line in f:
    replaceString.append(line.rstrip())
f.close()
replaceColors = "\n".join(replaceString)
print(replaceColors.replace("%REPLACE1%", "BLACKGREY"))
```

Output:

```
ÛÛ³    [x] Yellow      [ ] Yellow       [ ] Yellow      ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [x] Pink        [ ] Pink         [ ] %REPLACE3%  ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] Green       [ ] green        [ ] Green       ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] Red         [ ] red          [ ] Red         ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] Blue        [ ] blue         [ ] Blue        ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] Black       [ ] %REPLACE2%   [ ] black       ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] White       [ ] white        [ ] white       ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] grey        [ ] grey         [ ] grey        ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] brown       [ ] brown        [ ] brown       ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] BLACKGREY  [ ] orange       [ ] orange      ³ÛÛ
ÛÛ³    [ ] purple      [ ] purple       [ ] purple      ³ÛÛ
```

How it should be:

```
██│    [x] Yellow      [ ] Yellow       [ ] Yellow      │██
██│    [x] Pink        [ ] Pink         [ ] %REPLACE3%  │██
██│    [ ] Green       [ ] green        [ ] Green       │██
██│    [ ] Red         [ ] red          [ ] Red         │██
██│    [ ] Blue        [ ] blue         [ ] Blue        │██
██│    [ ] Black       [ ] %REPLACE2%   [ ] black       │██
██│    [ ] White       [ ] white        [ ] white       │██
██│    [ ] grey        [ ] grey         [ ] grey        │██
██│    [ ] brown       [ ] brown        [ ] brown       │██
██│    [ ] BLACKGREY   [ ] orange       [ ] orange      │██
██│    [ ] purple      [ ] purple       [ ] purple      │██
```

I don't want these "ÛÛ" in my new created file. I want to have the "blackboxes" like in the screen. Replacing is not the problem. Problem is the structure after loading the file into a string. when I write these string to a new file, the template does not look like in the screen shown.

Comment: Show your code.  Read how to create a [mcve].  Links are not appropriate as they can expire and make the question useless to future users.

Comment: Post text as *text*, you should be able to make a [mcve] including your existing attempts without needing any external links

Comment: Sorry, i edited my question. Hope its understandable. :) Thanks for your fast reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two problems here

1. reading and writing the data correctly
2. preserving the structure

**Reading and Writing**

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.nfo#History), .nfo files of this type are encoded with the cp437 text encoding.  Therefore this encoding must be specified when reading and writing the file.

```
with open('colors.nfo', 'r', encoding='cp437') as f:
    ...

with open('colors.nfo', 'w', encoding='cp437') as f:
    ...
```

Alternatively, the file may be opened in binary mode, and all operations carried out using bytes rather than text.

```
with open('colors.nfo', 'rb') as f:
    ...
```

If no encoding is specified, Python uses the system default, probably cp1252 in this case.An 8-bit encoding like cp1252 is able to decode the file, but where cp437 decodes `b'\xdb'` as 'FULL BLOCK' (█), cp1252 decodes it as 'LATIN CAPITAL LETTER U WITH CIRCUMFLEX' (Û), corrupting the data as seen in the question.

**Preserving Structure**

The data has a fixed-width format, so care must be taken when replacing text that the target and replacement strings are both of equal length, otherwise the columns will not be aligned correctly.

```
target = '%REPLACE1%'
replacement = 'BLACKGREY'

delta = len(target) - len(replacement)

padding = ' ' * abs(delta)
if delta > 0:
    replacement += padding
else:
    target += padding
```

**Solutions**

Here's a complete script.

```
replacements = { 
        '%REPLACE1%': 'BLACKGREY',
        '%REPLACE2%': 'REDWHITE',
}   

with open('colors.nfo', encoding='cp437') as f:
    data = f.read()

for target, replacement in replacements.items():
    delta = len(target) - len(replacement)
    padding = ' ' * abs(delta)
    if delta > 0:
        replacement += padding
    else:
        target += padding

    data = data.replace(target, replacement)

with open('new-colors.nfo', 'w', encoding='cp437') as f:
    f.write(data)
```

Processing as binary data is the same, except that the files are opened and closed in binary mode, and strings are declared as `bytes` rather than `str`.

```
replacements = { 
        b'%REPLACE1%': b'BLACKGREY',
        b'%REPLACE2%': b'REDWHITE',
}   

with open('colors.nfo', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

for target, replacement in replacements.items():
    delta = len(target) - len(replacement)
    padding = b' ' * abs(delta)
    if delta > 0:
        replacement += padding
    else:
        target += padding

    data = data.replace(target, replacement)

with open('new-colors.nfo', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data)
```